# specialize partially a class template member using enable_if

Tags: c++, c++17

How do you spectialize a class member only on arithmetic types ?

I want to obtain something like that:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    std::vector<T> member;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<enable_if_t<is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>> A<enable_if_t<is_arthmetic_v<T>, T>::member = {}
```

But this doesn't compile.

edit: I have found one solution :

```
template<typename T>
struct A_arit  {
    static std::vector<T> member;
}

template<typename T>
struct A_not_arit  {
    static std::vector<T> member;
}

template<typename T, class Parent = std::conditional_t<
      std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, A_arit<T>,
      A_nA<T>>>
struct A : public Parent  {
    using Parent::member;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> A_arit<T>::member = {elementsForArithmetics}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> A_not_arit<T>::member = {elementsForOthers}
```

but is there a more elegant way ?

Comment: I can't catch what you want to achieve! What should happen with member if T is of std::is_arithmetic. BTW: there is a typo in your "arthmetic"

Comment: Can you be more specific in "obtain something like that"? What is "that"? Default member value for arithmetic types only?

Comment: yes I want to set the static with two diferent elements for arithmetics and other types

Comment: I still can't see what is the target here! For me the result is exactly the same for both specializations...

Comment: I have edited my post, what I want is to set the vector with different elements for arithmetics and the others

Comment: Just specialize / overload a function you call for getting the initial value.

Comment: I can't do that without specializing the entire class, in the real case I have other template parameters

Comment: No, not really.  Your solution is pretty much the strategy used by the implementations of the standard libraries.